# Trouble Serializing JSON data for an object array from JS for Unity

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, webgl

I am trying to send data from JS to C# in Unity in a WebGL project, but I am not as familiar with javascript and JSON.

In the JS code, I am serializing an array of objects from js with Json.Stringify, and that is sent to Unity as a string. This is what comes through to Unity...

```
[
    [],[],[],[],
    [
        {
            "damage": 0,
            "opaque": false,
            "safe": false

        }
    ],

    [
        {
            "damage": 0,
            "opaque": false,
            "safe": false
        }
    ]
]
```

I did not write the js code, so I am not sure what exactly to post. If it seems like my Unity code is okay, I will try to see what I can share from js.

I am not sure why there are empty brackets above. I wonder if unity is getting stuck trying
to serialize those empty sets.

I made two Serializable classes in Unity for the incoming objects.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class minimap
{
    public int damage;
    public bool opaque;
    public bool safe;

}

[System.Serializable]
public class minimaps
{
    public minimap[] minimapArray;
}
```

On a gameObject, I placed a script that is called from JS.  The "Json convert completed" works, but the minimap loop does not. The array seems to have something in it, but not what I was hoping for unless I am not accessing it properly.

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public JsonDeserialize(string minimap)
    {
        minimaps minimaps = JsonUtility.FromJson<minimaps>(minimap);

        if(minimaps != null) _debugText.text += "JSON convert completed";

        foreach (minimap mm in minimaps.minimapArray)
        {
            _debugText.text += "Damage: " + mm.damage + "opaque: " + mm.opaque;
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks for reading and any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(minimap)
{
  minimap[][] minimaps = JsonUtility.FromJson<minimaps[][]>(minimap);

 if(minimaps!=null)
 {
  foreach (var mms in minimaps)
  {
      if(mms==null) _debugText.text ="Error: mms is null";
      else
       foreach (minimap mm in mms)
         _debugText.text += "Damage: " + mm.damage + "opaque: " + mm.opaque;
   }
 }
} else _debugText.text ="Error: minimaps is null";
} else _debugText.text ="Error: minimap is an empty string";
```

but I highly recommend you to google and istall Newtonsoft.Json for Unity3d

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

 minimap[][] minimaps = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<minimaps[][]>(minimap);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. It seems to work the same as what I was trying, nothing for _debugText from the mm.damage and or. opaque. You had the first minimap of your code I think missing the s, or maybe should have been FromJson<minimaps?

Comment: Getting this error 
'NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object' on this line 'foreach (minimap mm in mms)'

Comment: @Garbongalor I added some validation to the code

Comment: it's still coming out the same, I am assuming you meant to have
 
'minimaps[][] minimaps = JsonUtility.FromJson<minimaps[][]>(minimap);'

though that wont compile due to an error at the second foreach, 

if I do 'minimap[][] minimaps = JsonUtility.FromJson<minimap[][]>(minimap);' it will run but gets an error and stops at the second foreach.  The minimap string definitely has text.  It looks like an array of arrays of objects, and some of the arrays are null/invisible, and perhaps unity doesn't know what to do with that?

Comment: It ended up working with your code along with Newtonsoft.Json. Thank you so much for your time. You are an angel amongst men.